# i want to use IDBKeyRange.only() judging whether Date is equal

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

```js
function dataBaseFilter(filterIndex, range, callBack) {
  let objectStore = db.transaction([objectStoreName], "readwrite").objectStore(objectStoreName);
  let filter = objectStore.index(filterIndex);
  let rangeFilter = IDBKeyRange.only(range); //弄清其内在机制，==？
  let baseStruct;
  let documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  filter.openCursor(rangeFilter, "next").onsuccess = function(event) {
    cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
      let result = cursor.value;
      console.log(result);
      displaySomeThingAtOnce(result);
      baseStruct = getCompleteTask(result);
      documentFragment.appendChild(baseStruct);
      callBack(documentFragment);
      cursor.continue();
    }

  }

}
```

i want to use IDBKeyRange.only() judging whether Date is equal,but it won't work,i know why .But  if i have to use IDBKeyRange.only() judging whether Date is equal,what should i do?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, but I think it's hard for me to strip the code snippets involved in this issue from the whole project.

Comment: `cursor.continue` is a function, but you have specified it as a property.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much. But my confusion is, what should I do when the objects stored in indexedDB cannot be filtered by IDBKeyRange.only() ? Because this object is not a string, it is a Date object, and IDBKeyRange.only() can only use ==

Comment: if you are storing by dates, then query by dates. use a date object.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't understand what you mean, I have now given up using IDBKeyRange.only() as the filtering method. I store the TASK object, the date is just a property of TASK, and I can't use IDBKeyRange.only( ) Determine if the date objects are equal. Thanks again.